# Django Admin Interface doesn't Show App

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to follow this [To-Do Application tutorial (link)](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-to-do-list-30-minutes/) with some tiny differences on my system

- I use sqLite instead of mysql I use django 1.4 .
- I think tutorial was written before 1.4 released.

I have only one app as it's named in tutorial- todo. I'm trying to display app on django's admin interface but i can't manage to do that.

When i type python manage.py syncdb command on terminal, It gives me this error message:

[image: error message in terminal]

Below you can see my project's files.

---

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

# Create your models here.

# For this application, we will need two models:
#                                              one representing a list,
#                                              and one representing an item in a list.


# this class will be a database table named list
class List(models.Model): 

  title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True) 

  # __str__ method is like toString() in java
  def __str__(self): 

    return self.title 

  class Meta: 

    ordering = ['title'] 

  class Admin: 

    pass




# i need this for  Item Class    
import datetime 



PRIORITY_CHOICES = ( 

  (1, 'Low'), 

  (2, 'Normal'), 

  (3, 'High'), 

) 


# this class will be a database table named item
class Item(models.Model): 

  # this will create a charfield column named "title" in database
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250) 


  # created_date will be a DATETIME column in the database
  # datetime.datetime.now is a standard Python function
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now) 


  # default priority level will be 2 as in "Normal" in PRIORITY_CHOICES
  # using choices argument as choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES , Django will allow only 1,2 and 3 as we want to
  priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES, default=2) 


  # this will create a boolean column named "completed" in database
  completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  todo_list = models.ForeignKey(List) 

  def __str__(self): 

    return self.title 

  class Meta: 

    # We have specified that list items should be ordered by two columns: priority and title.
    # The - in front of priority tells Django to use descending order for the priority column,
    # so Django will include ORDER BY priority DESC title ASC in its queries whenever it deals with list items.
    ordering = ['-priority', 'title'] 

  class Admin: 

    pass
```

---

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/Users/ihtechnology/Desktop/envi/db_gtd/sqlite3.db', 
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # I ADDED MY APPLICATION HERE SO IN CAN BE INSTALLED INTO PROJECT AS OTHER DEFAULT DJANGO APPS
    'todo',
)
```

---

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

---

**admin.py**

```
from todo.models import List
from todo.models import Item
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(List)
admin.site.register(Item)
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're running `admin.autodiscover()` from within your `models` module, so the following happens during that call:

1. Django looks for all `admin` modules in all installed apps, imports them
2. Imports at the top of `admin` modules are of course run right when each `admin` is imported
3. The `admin` module imports `from todo.models import List` (presumably)
4. The `todo.models` module isn't available yet, because it was still being imported by `load_app` (6th frame from the bottom of your traceback) when `admin.autodiscover()` was run (3rd frame from the bottom of your traceback)

tl;dr

You just have a circular import, but I wanted to explain it so that it was clear why.

#### Solution

Move `admin.autodiscover()` to your main `urls` module.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused for `circular import` issue:

```
+--> +/todo/models.py #line 6
|    |
|    +->**admin.autodiscover()**
|      +
|      |
|      +-->/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py #line 29
|         +
|         |
|         +->/django/utils/importlib.py # line 35
|           +
|           |
|           +-->/todo/admin.py #line 1
|           |
|           +->from todo.models import List
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Your `admin` style is old, try new [admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) style.

Comment: I'm using django 1.4 and new admin style is started from 1.6
I solved the problem but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text 
def _str_(self) :
        return smart_text(self.title)
```

for title not displaying in django admin panel

Comment: I'm not sure this applies to this question; see the other answers for the root cause, which this does not appear to address at all.